# R - Collapse Data by Grouped Row Observations

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I'm working with a large data frame of hospitalization records. Many patients have two or more hospitalizations, and their past medical history may be incomplete at one or more of the hospitalizations. I'd like to collapse all the information from each of their hospitalizations into a single list of medical problems for each patient.

Here's a sample data frame:

```
 id <- c("123","456","789","101","123","587","456","789")
 HTN <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
 FALSE)
 DM2 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
 TIA <- c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)
 df <- data.frame(id,HTN,DM2,TIA)
 df
```

Which comes out to:

```
 > df
    id   HTN   DM2   TIA
 1 123  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 2 456 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 3 789 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 4 101 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 5 123 FALSE FALSE FALSE
 6 587  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 7 456 FALSE FALSE  TRUE
 8 789 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I'd like my output to look like this:

```
  id <- c("101","123","456","587","789")
  HTN <- c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
  DM2 <- c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE)
  TIA <- c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
  df2 <- data.frame(id,HTN,DM2,TIA)
  df2

    id  HTN  DM2 TIA
 1 101 FALSE  TRUE TRUE
 2 123  TRUE FALSE TRUE
 3 456 FALSE FALSE TRUE
 4 587  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
 5 789 FALSE  TRUE TRUE
```

So far I've got a pretty good hunch that arranging and grouping my data is the right place to start, and I think I could make it work by creating a new variable for each medical problem. I have about 30 medical problem's I'll need to collapse in this way, though, and that much repetitive code just seems like a recipe for an occult error.

```
 df3 <- df %>%
   arrange(id) %>%
   group_by(id)
```

Looking around I haven't been able to find a particularly elegant way to go about this. Is there some slick dplyr function I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize_all(any)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#   id    HTN   DM2   TIA  
#   <fct> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
# 1 101   FALSE TRUE  TRUE 
# 2 123   TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
# 3 456   FALSE FALSE TRUE 
# 4 587   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
# 5 789   FALSE TRUE  TRUE
```

In this way we first indeed group by `id`, as you suggested. Then we `summarize` `all` the variables with a function `any`: we provide a logical vector (e.g., `HTN` for patient `101`) and return `TRUE` if in any of the rows we have `TRUE` and `FALSE` otherwise.

Comment: This worked well for me. The only issue I encountered was that my dataframe actually contained a few other columns I wanted to keep, which summarize_all eliminated. This was easily overcome by making a separate key dataframe, using  and using left_join to recombine the two frames.

Comment: @BrianErly, great. Also you could take a look at `summarize_at`, perhaps it's easy to specify the names of the columns that you want to summarize.

Answer (score 1):

A base R option would be

```
aggregate(.~ id, df, any)
#   id   HTN   DM2  TIA
#1 101 FALSE  TRUE TRUE
#2 123  TRUE FALSE TRUE
#3 456 FALSE FALSE TRUE
#4 587  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
#5 789 FALSE  TRUE TRUE
```

---

Or with `rowsum`

```
rowsum(+(df[-1]), group = df$id) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If we prefer `data.table` we might use:

```
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, any), keyby = id]
    id   HTN   DM2  TIA
1: 101 FALSE  TRUE TRUE
2: 123  TRUE FALSE TRUE
3: 456 FALSE FALSE TRUE
4: 587  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
5: 789 FALSE  TRUE TRUE
```